# Свойство прототипа remove попадает в key при итерации объекта

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

```js
class AdminTags {

  constructor({
    jsonTags,
    dom
  }) {
    this.jsonTags = jsonTags;
    this.dom = dom;

    this.tags = {}; /* все тэги */
    this.same = []; /* совпадения */

    this.init();
  }

  /* преобразование json в объект */
  jsonParse() {
    this.tags = JSON.parse(this.jsonTags);
  }

  /* рендер столбцов */
  renderColumns() {
    let html = '';

    for (let key in this.tags) {
      html += `<div class="admin-tag-columns__item"><h4>${key}</h4>`;
      this.tags[key].forEach((item) => {

        let same = this.same.indexOf(item.name) + 1;
        html += `<div class="admin-tag__item ${same ? 'same' : ''}">
                                <div>${item.name}</div>
                                <div>${item.score}</div>
                            </div>`;
      });
      html += '</div>';
    }

    return html;
  }

  /* посчитать повторы */
  computedSame() {
    /* все тэги в общий массив */
    let allTags = [];
    for (let key in this.tags) {
      console.log(key);
      allTags = allTags.concat(this.tags[key].map((item) => item.name));
    }

    /* коллекция повторов */
    let same = [];
    allTags.forEach((item, n) => {
      if (allTags.indexOf(item, n + 1) + 1) {
        if (!(same.indexOf(item) + 1)) same.push(item);
      }
    });

    this.same = same;
  }

  /* рендер повторов */
  renderSame() {
    let html = '';

    if (!this.same.length) {
      this.dom.same.innerHTML = 'повторов нет';
      return false;
    }

    this.same.forEach((item) => {
      html += `<span>${item}</span>`;
    });

    return html;
  }

  /* расчитать и срендерить */
  runLogic() {
    this.jsonParse();

    this.computedSame();

    this.dom.columns.innerHTML = this.renderColumns();
    this.dom.same.innerHTML = this.renderSame();
  }


  clearData() {
    this.tags = {};
    this.same = []; /* clear совпадения */
  }


  /* первичная инициализация */
  init() {
    this.clearData();
    this.runLogic();
  }

}

const adminTags = new AdminTags({
  jsonTags: '<?= json_encode($this->autoTags, true) ?>',
  dom: {
    same: document.querySelector('.js-tags-same'),
    columns: document.querySelector('.admin-tag-columns')
  }
});
```

Есть класс AdminTags который отрисовывает списки тегов, приходящие в json формате. При листании фоточек я делаю следующее:

```js
adminTags.jsonTags = tagsFromAjax;
adminTags.init();
```

Я переопределяю json коллекцию тегов. и вызываю метод init - который парсит в объект, строит верстку и находит повторения.
При первом отрабатывании метода init (при создании экземпляра класса) все работает хорошо. При листании фоточек, если json представляет собой пустой json массив - при итерации объекта попадает метод remove из прототипа. Это подтверждает console.log(key) в коде.
Кто может подсказать - по какой причине такое может происходить?????

Answer (score 0):

Потому что при парсинге пустого json this.tags становится массивом =) А скрипт ожидает работу с объектом (итерация for in). И если провести небольшой эксперимент:

```js
let rrr = [];
for (let key in rrr) { console.log(key) }
```

То в консоль попадет remove.

Всем спасибо!